eSIM for China with a local number
I would like to get an eSIM with a Chinese number so I can use it to register for local services, apps and so on.
I'm aware that:

I can get a regular SIM in airports, but I'd like to save my SIM slot for my roaming SIM card.
I don't mind Internet restrictions on this eSIM. I expect to only use it to receive SMS verification codes and such.
I can get a travel eSIM (searched for "travel esim", "travel esim app" and "esim china") but I was unable to find one that gives a local phone number (at least Arialo and Nomad don't, I checked a few more of those search results).

I have tried:

3 HK offer eSIMs but not sure if their Mainland China Number Service applies to it, and can't get answers out of their support.
I previously used China Unicom HK physical SIM (跨境王) but they currently don't seem to offer any prepaid SIMs with Chinese numbers, let alone eSIMs - only long term plans.
How to choose an eSIM for China + Hong Kong? asks for eSIM in general, not Chinese numbers.
No eSIM providers listed in Prepaid Data SIM Card Wiki  offer Chinese numbers.


Wouldn't a dedicated feature phone with a regular SIM do the work at a low cost?
